# Where are the CloudSim migration : allocation and selection policies examples

Tags: java, cloud, simulation, cloudsim

Where can i find the VM allocation and selection policies for migration ? and also, in github i found many versions of CloudSim, but the problem is that the version 3 still the most clear and clean one, i don't know why in some releases they don't include the docs like in version 3.0.3, also in cloudsim 4, i found two packages, one that includes only the class files, and the other with the source files, i mean why don't they just put everything in one single asset, and in the main repository they did't include the docs folder, even though it's really important, also they did't include the jar folder that has the jar files which contains source and classes with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the allocation and selection policies that I've been looking for, in CloudSim 3 they were in the: "examples/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/power/random/" directory, in which we can find the Mmt, Lr ...etc.
And the examples combining those policies are in: "org/cloudbus/cloudsim/power/" folder.
[Migration Examples Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyydY.png)[Migration Policies Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR6an.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you try CloudSim Plus, there is a package containing some [migration examples here](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/tree/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/migration).

> in github i found many versions of CloudSim, but the problem is that the version 3 still the most clear and clean one

CloudSim Plus is based on CloudSim 3.0.3 and is way clearer, more organized, documented and structured, making it really easier to understand and extend.

> i don't know why in some releases they don't include the docs like in version 3.0.3, also in cloudsim 4, i found two packages, one that includes only the class files, and the other with the source files, i mean why don't they just put everything in one single asset, and in the main repository they did't include the docs folder, even though it's really important, also they did't include the jar folder that has the jar files which contains source and classes with examples.

If you download the source code for CloudSim or CloudSim Plus, you get everything you need. After opening the project in some IDE and building it, the javadocs and jar files will be generated inside the `target` dir.

In the case of CloudSim Plus, since it's available on Maven Central, you don't even need to download the sources to build the javadocs and jars, you just need to include it as a dependency inside your own project that Maven will download everything for you.

But if you want to check the documentation online, CloudSim Plus provides [this link](http://cloudsimplus.rtfd.io).